# Encoding from pull data from database to reading in from .txt file

Tags: encoding

Would like to run this by you.

When I try to read data into my programing space from a database it won't read certain strings (names with special characters are being corrupted).

However, when I read the data straight from source (a .txt file) which hasn't gone through the database strings are appearing fine.

I presume this is some encoding issue? I need to match the encoding which is in the database in order to display the data correctly?

Any ideas would be great

Comment: You tagged the question only with [encoding] and gave no information about the database, encoding, "programming space" (whatever this means), programming language, [mre] of your code etc. Please read [ask] and edit your question, and add relevant tags.